# Can I use databricks notebook to re-structure blobs and save it in another azure storage account?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have incoming blobs in azure storage account for every day-hour, now I want to modulate the structure of the JSON inside the blobs and injest them into azure data lake.

I am using azure data factory and databricks.

Can Someone let me know how to proceed with it? I have mounted blob to databricks but now how to create a new structure and then do the mapping?